# I am having problem in paralleltable and parallel sum ( Parallel computation in Mathematica)

Tags: parallelization, mathematica-online

[You will receive the code here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m9Z1jG_5zBo1_h4tmi3hQrS-7hw-nQBF/view?usp=sharing)

I want to do parallel computation here because I have planning to go further level and it will take a much longer time. I could not understand what this error means and how to deal with it.

Here is the error....
[[image: Error][2]]

Comment: Unfortunately, your screen shot is quite unreadabe and please do not ask to download code from the internet, put everything into the question, properly condensed to the real issue. And, by the way the error message is quite clear...  Just do not nest parallel comps.

Comment: The error is "Parallel computations cannot be nested" You have nested `ParallelTable[ParallelSum[...]]`. That is not permitted.